# Dynamic overwriting magic methods in python

Tags: python, magic-methods

I am looking for proper solution for this code I've made. I just want to have possibility to print my XML while it's still building.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document, DOMImplementation

class MyClass(object):

init():
    pass

def create_xml():
  doc = Document()
  # I know i cannot do that, I know. I need proper solution for that
  doc.__str__ = self.print_doc

def print_doc(document):
    return document.toprettyxml(encoding='UTF-8')
```

We're able to figure out a not clean way for it, that works, so you can see my idea here:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document, DOMImplementation

def create_xml():
  doc = Document()
  document.__str__ = partial(self.print_doc, document=document)

def print_doc(document):
    return document.toprettyxml(encoding='UTF-8')
```

My class needs to be static, as software cannot handle more, than one instance during whole run, still user has to create more than one xml during that run (yes, this is messed up, but that i cannot help).
Instead making weird things, I did smth that will work for me:

```
class Child(Document):
   def __str__(self):
      return document.toprettyxml(encoding='UTF-8')
```

...so this class allows me to print

```
class MyClass(object):

def create_xml():
  return Document()
```

...all that, beacause i have to have

```
def main():
    xml = MyClass.create()
    print(xml)
```

...instead just

```
xml = Document()
```

Sorry everyone for confusing... i guess planing here is what i messed up first

Comment: You only want do what you've written because `self` doesn't exist there. Try `doc.__str__ = print_doc`.

Comment: Your allegedly working code is not user-friendly because it doesn't actually work but other than that I don't see why you say it's not human-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just subclass `Document`?

```
class MyDoc(Document):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.toprettyxml(encoding='UTF-8')
```

You can also create a wrapper class:

```
class DocumentWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, doc):
        self.doc = doc  # doc should be a "Document".
    def __str__(self):
        return self.doc.toprettyxml(encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: 1) This is meant to be static class. Parser is based on Document, but only my methods should be visible. Sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: @user2678074 I don't quite understand. You never said anything about "only my methods should be visible" before. And what is a "static class" in Python? Could you [edit] your question and explain why the subclassing approach doesn't work or include an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I will. Please, give me a second

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand, but if you want to override a method, just override it :)

```
class XMLDoc(Document):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.toprettyxml(encoding='UTF-8')

myxml = XMLDoc([.. args ..])
print str(myxml)
```